# GTK header files not found when compiling c code in arch linux

Tags: c, linux, unix, gcc, gtk

I am attempting to compile code using the <gtk/gtk.h> header file using gcc. Whenever I do so I get the following error:

> gtk.c:3:10: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
>
> 3 | #include <gtk/gtk.h>
> ^~~~~~~~~~~

I have looked in /usr/include/ and found gtk-1.2 gtk-2.0 and gtk-3.0 all of which have the header files within them necessary to compile the program I'm unsure why GCC can't find those files and how to reroute gcc to find the necessary header files.

Comment: Did you set the include path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC doesn't know which version you want to use. GTK recommends using pkg-config to compile programs. For example, for GTK 3 use:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` yourprogram.c -o yourprogram `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

You could also specify the correct include and library paths yourself.